# How to implement server side count down timer

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

what I want to do is when some record get added in table the countdown timer will start for that record and as soon as it hits zero it will trigger some server side action. I want it server side because it should continue when user is not online or logged in. I am using asp.net, C#, SQL.

Comment: where do you want to raise the action? in SQL?

Comment: How long is this timer going to run for? Are we talking *computer* scales (ms) or *human* scales (seconds, minutes, longer)?

Comment: yes i want to raise action in sql like some sql query or stored procedure.  the timer should run for 2 days(Human scales (seconds,minutes))

Comment: Could you not just do the action the next time the user does any interaction and the time has passed? Does it need to happen at the given time?

Comment: it need to happen as soon as timer hits 0, regardless of whether user logs in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this (as with everything in programming!).

The way I usually do this is to store a timestamp in the database which is checked every time the user (or any user affected by it) does any type of interaction. If the timestamp has passed, the event should be invoked.

Another way of doing this (if i remember right, this is how laravel does its jobs) is to do as the above, but instead of relying on user interaction, a cronjob or scheduled job of some sort is the trigger to check the user/s.
So every time the cronjob fires (depending on how close to the time it has to be, the job could fire every second if wanted) it will check each user to see if their timestamp is older than current timestamp, and in that case, invoke the event.

Comment: i am newbie to cronjob & scheduling events can you guide me in right direction regarding this with an example? thanks in advance

Comment: I would love to, but I'm just about to leave the house, so I can not do it right now. I would recommend checking google or SO for info, if you use Linux, search for Cronjob or Crontab and if you use Windows, check for Task scheduler. There should be plenty of good info on the net! :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using a windows service in server machine, its more reliable to ensure the consistency in real time data.

- Add data in db.
- In Window service set the frequency to every second, it will check for the newly inserted data.
- once the windows service reads the data (finds the new data in table), start the timer in thread, it will run continuously for several days.
- finally windows service will do the server sided action.